# cannot remove specific views in android

Tags: android

I have a problem in removing views.

```
     ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) lastImageSelected.getParent();

                int x = owner.getChildCount();
                for(int i=0; i<=x; i++) {
                    View currentChild = owner.getChildAt(i);
                    if (currentChild != mainImage && currentChild != zoomIn 
                            && currentChild != zoomOut && currentChild != rotatePoint) {
                        owner.removeView(currentChild);
                        owner.invalidate();
                    }
                }
```

This code is working, but everytime I delete, all views are not deleting. I think all odd numbers(index) is not deleting.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you call `invalidate` within the loop. This resets the view positions:

**Iteration #1**

- `owner.removeView(0);` // View at `0` is removed.
- `invalidate()` // now each view shifts one positionn back,  View at `1` is moved to position `0`

**Iteration #2**

- `owner.removeView(1);` // View at `1` is removed. (this was originally at `2`)
- `invalidate()` // now View at `2` (originally at `3`) is moved to position `1`

and so on..

Try this:

```
ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) lastImageSelected.getParent();

int x = owner.getChildCount();
for(int i=0; i<=x; i++) {
    View currentChild = owner.getChildAt(i);
    if (currentChild != mainImage && currentChild != zoomIn 
            && currentChild != zoomOut && currentChild != rotatePoint) {
        owner.removeView(currentChild);       
    }
}
owner.invalidate();
```

**Note:**

`invalidating` once will be much faster (efficient) than calling it within the loop `n` number of times.

Answer (score 0):

```
  ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) lastImageSelected.getParent();

                    int x = owner.getChildCount();
                    for(int i=0; i<=x; i++) {
                        View currentChild = owner.getChildAt(0);//<---- just change i to 0
                        if (currentChild != mainImage && currentChild != zoomIn 
                                && currentChild != zoomOut && currentChild != rotatePoint) {
                            owner.removeView(currentChild);
                            owner.invalidate();
                        }
                    }
```